# Encrypt \ Decrypt an Integer where the encrypted value is an Integer

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I have a sequential list of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. These numbers are stored as an integer, which will be returned via an Api i.e. 3. I want some way to encrypt the number so instead of returning 3 it will be 5832 (or some other int) that I can then decrypt to get back to 3.
I've looked at various encryption posts mentioning AES, Feistel cipher, etc but they all seem to return an alphanumeric string rather than an integer.
Is there a way to achieve this so that i can encrypt an integer and have an encrypted value also as an integer ?

Comment: Mapping one integer to another isn't encryption. HTTPS already does a far better job at encrypting requests and responses than this. AES and the other algorithms encrypt bytes, not strings. Those bytes are encoded into strings using BASE64.

Comment: you could XOR them with some known (to you) number [`^`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption

Comment: Note that an "Integer" is just a sequence of bytes. On most systems `int` is 4 bytes. When you encrypt **anything**, you are encrypting the binary / byte form. The result is also in a binary / byte form. Viewing bytes as integers, strings, or whatever your data type is just a way to interpret the bytes based on some context.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the following procedure can be used. The numbers are written in binary to the stream and encrypted using the AES method according to the set password. The resulting bytes are read as numbers into the encrypted form. This can then be read back by rewriting the numbers into the stream and reading them through the decryptor. The only downside is that the encrypted numbers contain two extra numbers, because AES stores the key (not the password, that's not stored anywhere).

```
var data = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    data[i] = Random.Shared.Next(100);
Console.WriteLine("input data: {0}", String.Join(", ", data));

var encData = Encrypt(data, "1");
Console.WriteLine("encrypted data: {0}", String.Join(", ", encData));

var decData = Decrypt(encData, "1");
Console.WriteLine("decrypted data: {0}", String.Join(", ", decData));


int[] Encrypt(int[] inputData, string password)
{
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())   // System.Security.Cryptography
    {
        aes.Key = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        aes.IV = new byte[16];
        var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        var result = new List<int>();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                foreach (var i in inputData)
                    bw.Write(i);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(ms))
                while (ms.Position < ms.Length)
                    result.Add(br.ReadInt32());
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}

int[] Decrypt(int[] encryptedData, string password)
{
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())  
    {
        aes.Key = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        aes.IV = new byte[16];
        var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        var result = new List<int>();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, true))
                foreach (var i in encryptedData)
                    bw.Write(i);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(cs))
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                            result.Add(br.ReadInt32());
                    } catch (EndOfStreamException) { }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```